# How to list every JSON Array element separately within MySQL Query?

Tags: mysql, json, select

I have written following `MySQL` Json Array query. The Mysql version is `8.0.18-commercial`

```
select 
networkInfo->>"$.*" as network,
servers->>"$[*]" as server
from table1
where id = 56;
```

The output has 2 columns `network` and `server` of JSON type

```
network              server
---                  ---
[                    [
    "Linux123",          "Server123",
    "RHEL",              "Server1231",
    "abc.com"            "Server1232"
]                    ]
```

I want to modify the `SELECT` query such that the output has a separate row for every `server`:

```
network                      server
---                          ----  
[                             Server123
    "Linux123",
    "RHEL",
    "abc.com"
]

[                             Server1231
    "Linux123",
    "RHEL",
    "abc.com"
]

[                             Server1232
    "Linux123",
    "RHEL",
    "abc.com"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) to extract the different `server` values from `servers`, then `CROSS JOIN` that to the `networks` value for the given `id`:

```
SELECT t1.networkInfo->>"$.*" AS network, j.server
FROM table1 t1
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(t1.servers, 
                      "$[*]" COLUMNS (
                        server VARCHAR(20) PATH '$'
                        )
                      ) j
WHERE t1.id = 56
```

Output (I've had to hack up a [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7YRdDGrMqJGguWXVVkBaQt/0) based on an expectation of table structure):

```
network                             server
["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server123
["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server1231
["abc.com", "Linux123", "RHEL"]     Server1232
```